# Combo box set to visible in code behind, but won't display on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, telerik, radcombobox

I've a bit of a problem with Telerik radcomboboxes not updating properly on an aspx page.  Essentially a user picks a choice 'yes' or 'no' from radcombobox 1.  If the user chooses 'yes' then radcombobox 2 should show and radcombobox 3 should be hidden; if the user chooses 'no' then radcombobox 3 should show and radcombobox 2 should be hidden.

The code behind is vb.net. On the aspx page, combo box 1 is ajaxed and supposed to update the other two radcomboboxes.  In the code behind in the SelectedIndexChanged sub for radcombobox 1, the 'visible' property of the radcombobox 2 and 3 are swapped depending on the user's choice.

The problem is that the radcomboboxes do not appear to be swapping (i.e., updating on the aspx page) unless the page is reloaded, which I'm assuming happens because reloading the page is in essence forcing a postback.

I don't want to force a postback to fix this issue as I feel like that's a brute force workaround, and I want to understand why the logic isn't working as it should.

Here's the actual code below.  I used generic names for the radcomboboxes above.

```
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="cboX2">
<UpdatedControls>
    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="cboKey" />
    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="cboKey_X2" />
</UpdatedControls>
```

Here's the code from combo box 1 SelectedIndexChanged sub:

```
    If Me.cboKey.Visible = True OrElse Me.cboKey_X2.Visible = True Then
If piX2 <> 0 Then
    Me.cboKey.Visible = False
    Me.cboKey_X2.Visible = True
ElseIf piX2 = 0 Then
    Me.cboKey_X2.Visible = False
    Me.cboKey.Visible = True
End If
```

End If

Any help understanding why this doesn't work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox3" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
        </asp:Panel>
```

with such an AJAX setting:

```
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Probably, for some reason, the other combo boxes do not get updated. Most likely, because they are Visible=false by default, so RadAjaxManager cannot wrap an UpdatePanel around them to update them, because they simply do not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I did try adding a panel, but am still getting the same results.  The combo boxes are on a user control that is embedded in the aspx page, so perhaps there is something going on that is causing interference.

Comment: first, try removing ALL AJAX. If things work fine, then the problem is that the needed controls do not travel on the client. In this case, examine the network response when AJAX is enabled and see what's included and what is not in order to fix your AJAX setup. There is always the possibility that you have a server/JavaScript error that breaks things, so step through your server code and monitor your browser console to fix them.

Comment: Due to the complexity of the pages (and timeline restrictions), I decided to go another route and have updated the page to rebind a single combo box based on the user's selection in the initial combo box, rather than trying to hide/show two combo boxes.  Thank you very much for your time and help!!